# dealing with commas in strings in csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm practicing some text mining with python using this dataset
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat

Everything is nicely formatted but some entries like:

```
6898,"RAAF Williams, Laverton Base","Laverton","Australia",\N,"YLVT",-37.86360168457031,144.74600219726562,18,10,"O","Australia/Hobart","airport","OurAirports"   
6899,"Nowra Airport","Nowra","Australia","NOA","YSNW",-34.94889831542969,150.53700256347656,400,10,"O","Australia/Sydney","airport","OurAirports"
```

have commas in their names and that makes irregular lists, since it creates multiple elements of the same core element (name)

My code for assigning each line to a list:

```
with open (filename) as txt:
for line in txt:
    linea = line.split(',')
    linea[3]=linea[3].strip('"')
```

My main problem is that `linea[3]` should be the country `australia` in this case, but it returns `Laverton`.

I also tried the csv library with little to no difference.

Also relevant: my code returns this for that entry

```
['6898', 'RAAF Williams, Laverton Base', 'Laverton', 'Australia', '\\N', 'YLVT', '-37.86360168457031', '144.74600219726562', '18', '10', 'O', 'Australia/Hobart', 'airport', 'OurAirports']
```

Comment: Did you try pandas read_csv? `split(',')` is not correct at all

Comment: Your output does not match your problem description, `'Australia'` is at index 3 just like you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to change to another package: you can read the file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')

print df

     0                             1         2          3    4     5          6           7    8   9  10                11       12              13
0  6898  RAAF Williams, Laverton Base  Laverton  Australia   \N  YLVT -37.863602  144.746002   18  10  O  Australia/Hobart  airport  OurAirports   
1  6899                 Nowra Airport     Nowra  Australia  NOA  YSNW -34.948898  150.537003  400  10  O  Australia/Sydney  airport     OurAirports

# this line will give you the same output structure as you have with the csv package (i.e. the list of lists)
df.as_matrix()

[[6898 'RAAF Williams, Laverton Base' 'Laverton' 'Australia' '\\N' 'YLVT'
  -37.86360168457031 144.74600219726562 18 10 'O' 'Australia/Hobart'
  'airport' 'OurAirports   ']
 [6899 'Nowra Airport' 'Nowra' 'Australia' 'NOA' 'YSNW' -34.948898315429695
  150.53700256347656 400 10 'O' 'Australia/Sydney' 'airport' 'OurAirports']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python has supported csv parsing for a long time.[Refer this link.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

You need to use a `quotechar` in the parser. Basically, any commas between 2 occurrences of the quotechar will be ignored.

eg:

```
import csv
with open (filename) as csvfile:
   csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
   for row in csvreader:
       # do something with the row
       print row
```

Comment: i tried that exact code, same result

Comment: I've tried it with the airports.dat file you've posted. It works just fine. Are you sure you've used the *exact code*?